# TikZ Grid Without Edges

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids

I have the following Ti*k*Z grid:

[image: Current Output]

But I'd like to draw the grid without edges, or with half of the edges cells missing, so that it appears to be a small section of a larger, infinite grid. What's the best way to achieve this?

```
\documentclass[border=0.25cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (0,0) grid (3.5,3.5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, maybe `help lines` instead of `color=gray`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you make the coordinates not an exact multiple of the step size you can get this effect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (.75,.75) grid (3.75,3.75);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 15):

If you care for something a bit fancier, you could also try that one:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray,path fading=south] (.99,.75) grid (3.5,1);
   \draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray,path fading=north] (.99,3.5) grid (3.5,3.75);
   \draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray,path fading=west] (.75,.99) grid (1,3.5);
   \draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray,path fading=east] (3.5,.99) grid (3.75,3.5);
   \draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (1,1) grid (3.5,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Possible : `\begin{tikzpicture}[styling/.style={step=0.5cm,color=gray,path fading=#1}]`  then `styling=south` etc. and `styling=none` for the last path.

Answer (score 10):

I needed the same thing, but had things in the cells of the grid, which I also wanted to fade out. This solution is perhaps less elegant than others, but permits this sort of fading.

It just puts fading rectangles over the edges so they fade out to white.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[step=0.5cm] (0.1,0.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
    % Some letters to demonstrate fading
    \node at (0.25,0.25) {F};
    \node at (0.75,0.75) {A};
    \node at (1.25,0.25) {D};
    \node at (1.75,0.75) {E};

    \begin{scope}[transparency group]
        % Left edge
        \fill[path fading=east, color=white] (0,0) rectangle (1,4);
        % Bottom edge
        \fill[path fading=north, color=white] (0,0) rectangle (4,1);
        % Right edge
        \fill[path fading=west, color=white] (3,0) rectangle (4,4);
        % Top edge
        \fill[path fading=south, color=white] (0,3) rectangle (4,4);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oooo.... this is beautiful :-)

Answer (score 6):

You could draw some additional lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.5cm,color=gray] (0,0) grid (3.5,3.5);
\foreach \i in {0,0.5,...,3.5}
  {
  \draw[gray] (3.5,\i) -- (3.8,\i);
  \draw[gray] (0,\i) -- (-0.3,\i);
  \draw[gray] (\i,3.5) -- (\i,3.8);
  \draw[gray] (\i,0) -- (\i,-0.3);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

With PSTricks,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,multido}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4.5,-4.5)(4.5,4.5)
\multido{\ix=-4+1}{9}
{
    \psline(\ix,4.5)(\ix,-4.5)
    \psline(4.5,\ix)(-4.5,\ix)
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]