# Properly fading out grids

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm working on an illustration of a particular multiscale analysis method.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=1.5,
    circ/.style = {
        circle,
        draw,
        black!75,
        outer sep=0pt,
        inner sep=1pt
    }
]

    \begin{scope}[step=0.5, very thin, black!30]
        \draw [xshift=-2.5cm] (-0.9, -1) grid (1, 1);
        \draw [] (-1, -1) grid (1, 1);
        \draw [xshift=2.5cm] (-1, -1) grid (0.9, 1);
    \end{scope}

    \filldraw[fill=blue!40!white, fill opacity=0.5, draw=blue!50!white, very thin] (-0.5, -1) rectangle (0.5, 1);

    \foreach \y in {-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1} {
        \foreach \x in {-0.5, 0, 0.5} {
            \node [circ, fill=black!75] (enode) at (\x, \y) {};
        }
        \foreach \x in {-1.5, -1, 1, 1.5} {
            \node [circ, fill=white] (bnode) at (\x, \y) {};
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The above code produces the following result:

[image: DDM]

I'm now, out of general interest and in an attempt to become better at Ti*k*Z, trying to put the finishing touches to the figure and try and fade the five hanging horizontal line segments of the left and right subdomains to white without affecting the rest of the subdomain.

My attempt to reproduce the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102042/169291) by Ilhan Polat leads to an error that the counter variable `\x` is undefined. Another [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36204/169291), by Jean-Christophe Dubacq, to a similar question does not work as expected — I assume this is because the grid is not centered and `transform`-ing the fade doesn't work either.

Could someone please lend a hand and explain how to do this in an elegant way, or, at all? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  For future reference, while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.  This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries and sometimes this takes time to figure out.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thank you. In the future I will make sure that the MWE compiles directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do this on my own but prefer the look of the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/448214/169291) by Peter Grill. Simply create another column and apply the fade to them:

[image: DDM]

The artifact on the right does not appear in the PDF. Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
             scale=1.5,
             circ/.style = {
                 circle,
                 draw,
                 black!75,
                 outer sep=0pt,
                 inner sep=1pt
             }
        ]

        \begin{scope}[step=0.5, very thin, black!30]
            \draw [xshift=-3.5cm, path fading=west] (-0.5, -1) grid (0, 1);
            \draw [xshift=-2.5cm] (-1, -1) grid (1, 1);
            \draw [] (-1, -1) grid (1, 1);
            \draw [xshift=2.5cm] (-1, -1) grid (1, 1);
            \draw [xshift=3.5cm, path fading=east] (0, -1) grid (0.5, 1);
        \end{scope}

        \filldraw[fill=blue!40!white, fill opacity=0.5, draw=blue!50!white, very thin] (-0.5, -1) rectangle (0.5, 1);

        \foreach \y in {-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1} {
            \foreach \x in {-0.5, 0, 0.5} {
                \node [circ, fill=black!75] (enode) at (\x, \y) {};
            }
            \foreach \x in {-1.5, -1, 1, 1.5} {
                \node [circ, fill=white] (bnode) at (\x, \y) {};
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It should also be possible to create custom [shadings](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383134/how-is-a-pgf-shading-applied) and [clip](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49039/clipping-elements-in-tikz) them to accomplish an analogous effect when working on more complex shapes where such tricks do not apply.

Edit: Upon further review, this is the same as employed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36204/169291) by Dubacq. I misread.

Comment: You probably can clip the fading but still need to draw the non-faded part separately. So, not sure there is any benefit in trying to clip the fading.

Answer (score 4):

Not, sure if this is what you are looks for, but with the `\usetikzlibrary{fadings}` you can use `path fading=west` on the lines on the left and `path fading=east` on the right hand side

```
    \begin{scope}[step=0.5, very thin, black!30]
        \draw [xshift=-2.5cm, path fading=west] (-0.9, -1) grid (1, 1);
        \draw [] (-1, -1) grid (1, 1);
        \draw [xshift=2.5cm, path fading=east] (-1, -1) grid (0.9, 1);
    \end{scope}
```

to achieve:

[image]

If you just want the hanging parts to fade, not the squares, then draw them separately using:

```
\begin{scope}[step=0.5, very thin, black!30]
    \draw [xshift=-2.5cm] (-0.5, -1) grid (1, 1);
    \draw [xshift=-2.5cm, path fading=west] (-0.9, -1) grid (-0.5, 1);
    \draw [] (-1, -1) grid (1, 1);
    \draw [xshift=2.5cm] (-1, -1) grid (0.5, 1);
    \draw [xshift=2.5cm, , path fading=east] (0.5, -1) grid (0.9, 1);
\end{scope}
```

which yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    scale=1.5,
    circ/.style = {
        circle,
        draw,
        black!75,
        outer sep=0pt,
        inner sep=1pt
    }
]

    \begin{scope}[step=0.5, very thin, black!30]
        \draw [xshift=-2.5cm, path fading=west] (-0.9, -1) grid (1, 1);
        \draw [] (-1, -1) grid (1, 1);
        \draw [xshift=2.5cm, path fading=east] (-1, -1) grid (0.9, 1);
    \end{scope}

    \filldraw[fill=blue!40!white, fill opacity=0.5, draw=blue!50!white, very thin] 
        (-0.5, -1) rectangle (0.5, 1);

    \foreach \y in {-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1} {
        \foreach \x in {-0.5, 0, 0.5} {
            \node [circ, fill=black!75] (enode) at (\x, \y) {};
        }
        \foreach \x in {-1.5, -1, 1, 1.5} {
            \node [circ, fill=white] (bnode) at (\x, \y) {};
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I managed to achieve this on my own and honestly prefer what this looks like over what I wanted. However, out of interest: How would I do this "without affecting the rest of the subdomain", ie. make only the *hanging* segments fade out and not the other squares, as stated in the original post? I cannot find anything like this even in the Tikz / PGF manual.

Comment: @user169291: I am not sure I understand the difference between what is shown here and "make only the hanging segments fade out and not the other squares".  Please clarify.

Comment: @user169291: Have updated the answer. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yes, drawing them separately is what I was looking for; I submitted an answer to my own question.